# Open two home pages in Firefox

Tags: firefox

Is there a way to have Firefox open multiple tabs on start up?

Not the tabs from last session, but, say, Gmail, Google Voice, and Super User. Is this possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Under menu *Tools * → *Options*, go to the "Main" tab.

Under the Home Page text box where you key in your home page, just separate addresses with the pipe symbol (the one above your <kbd>Enter</kbd> key usually).

*E.g.,* www.google.com | www.huffingtonpost.com | superusers.com

will open up three tabs whenever you start Firefox.

Comment: What keyboard are you using? The pipe simple on my keyboard can only be accesed using ALTGR+1

Comment: Er... US keyboard layout? :) The question should be what keyboard are **YOU** using?

Comment: No. The question should be: "then why don't you simply press AltGr+1?"

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, open all the pages you wish to load automatically when Firefox starts, and then go to menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Main* → *Startup*. Make sure to select *When Firefox starts Show my home page* and hit the button *Use Current Pages*.